# Can I detect whether or not a Jenkins build has finished based on a queue URL?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to trigger a Jenkins build and wait until it has completed.

When I start Jenkins via its REST API, I get a resonse with a URL like `http://JENKINS_URL:8080/queue/item/36285/`.

When I try to access it, I always the get the 404 error. My test builds are rather short therefore it is possible that they are finished before I exit the debugger.

Question: Is it guaranteed that if a URL like `http://JENKINS_URL:8080/queue/item/36285/` results in a 404 response, then the corresponding Jenkins build is finished? That is, can I use this URL to find out whether or not it is finished (as long as the URL returns a status code not equal to 404, the build is running)?

Comment: No, the items get taken out of the queue when the job starts. It could be finished, or the job could still be running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/queue/item/` give you items in queue, that waiting to start and 404 means item not in the queue, can be canceled or in execution. Job execution can be in running, finished or canceled statuses.

You can use `queueId` (`36285` in your example), get job details and get build status for the particular `queueId`. In the response for the request below is job details with builds. You can find build you need by `queueId` in `builds` and get `building`(boolean) and `result` status:

```
JENKINS_URL+"/job/"+ artifactToBuild +"/api/json?depth=1'
```

Response example for `JENKINS_URL+"/job/"+ artifactToBuild +"/api/json?depth=1'`:

```json
{
  "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
  "actions": [],
  "description": "",
  "displayName": "my_job_name",
  "displayNameOrNull": null,
  "fullDisplayName": "my_job_name",
  "fullName": "my_job_name",
  "name": "my_job_name",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/",
  "buildable": true,
  "builds": [
    {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
      "actions": [],
      "artifacts": [],
      "building": false,
      "description": null,
      "displayName": "#1",
      "duration": 1651,
      "estimatedDuration": 1671,
      "executor": null,
      "fullDisplayName": "my_job_name #1",
      "id": "1",
      "keepLog": false,
      "number": 1,
      "queueId": 103,
      "result": "SUCCESS",
      "timestamp": 1580946018635,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/1/",
      "changeSets": [],
      "culprits": [],
      "nextBuild": {
        "number": 2,
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/2/"
      },
      "previousBuild": null
    }
  ],
  "color": "aborted",
  "firstBuild": {},
  "healthReport": [
    {
      "description": "Build stability: No recent builds failed.",
      "iconClassName": "icon-health-80plus",
      "iconUrl": "health-80plus.png",
      "score": 100
    }
  ],
  "inQueue": false,
  "keepDependencies": false,
  "lastBuild": {
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [],
    "artifacts": [],
    "building": false,
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "#10",
    "duration": 1238044,
    "estimatedDuration": 1671,
    "executor": null,
    "fullDisplayName": "my_job_name #10",
    "id": "10",
    "keepLog": false,
    "number": 10,
    "queueId": 587,
    "result": "ABORTED",
    "timestamp": 1581534463735,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/10/",
    "changeSets": [],
    "culprits": [],
    "nextBuild": null,
    "previousBuild": {
      "number": 9,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/9/"
    }
  },
  "lastCompletedBuild": {
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [],
    "artifacts": [],
    "building": false,
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "#10",
    "duration": 1238044,
    "estimatedDuration": 1671,
    "executor": null,
    "fullDisplayName": "my_job_name #10",
    "id": "10",
    "keepLog": false,
    "number": 10,
    "queueId": 587,
    "result": "ABORTED",
    "timestamp": 1581534463735,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/10/",
    "changeSets": [],
    "culprits": [],
    "nextBuild": null,
    "previousBuild": {
      "number": 9,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/9/"
    }
  },
  "lastFailedBuild": null,
  "lastStableBuild": {
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [],
    "artifacts": [],
    "building": false,
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "#2",
    "duration": 1671,
    "estimatedDuration": 1671,
    "executor": null,
    "fullDisplayName": "my_job_name #2",
    "id": "2",
    "keepLog": false,
    "number": 2,
    "queueId": 105,
    "result": "SUCCESS",
    "timestamp": 1580946027378,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/2/",
    "changeSets": [],
    "culprits": [],
    "nextBuild": {
      "number": 3,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/3/"
    },
    "previousBuild": {
      "number": 1,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/1/"
    }
  },
  "lastSuccessfulBuild": {
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [],
    "artifacts": [],
    "building": false,
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "#2",
    "duration": 1671,
    "estimatedDuration": 1671,
    "executor": null,
    "fullDisplayName": "my_job_name #2",
    "id": "2",
    "keepLog": false,
    "number": 2,
    "queueId": 105,
    "result": "SUCCESS",
    "timestamp": 1580946027378,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/2/",
    "changeSets": [],
    "culprits": [],
    "nextBuild": {
      "number": 3,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/3/"
    },
    "previousBuild": {
      "number": 1,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/1/"
    }
  },
  "lastUnstableBuild": null,
  "lastUnsuccessfulBuild": {
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [],
    "artifacts": [],
    "building": false,
    "description": null,
    "displayName": "#10",
    "duration": 1238044,
    "estimatedDuration": 1671,
    "executor": null,
    "fullDisplayName": "my_job_name #10",
    "id": "10",
    "keepLog": false,
    "number": 10,
    "queueId": 587,
    "result": "ABORTED",
    "timestamp": 1581534463735,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/10/",
    "changeSets": [],
    "culprits": [],
    "nextBuild": null,
    "previousBuild": {
      "number": 9,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/my_job_name/9/"
    }
  },
  "nextBuildNumber": 11,
  "property": [
    {
      "_class": "hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty"
    },
    {
      "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.DisableConcurrentBuildsJobProperty"
    }
  ],
  "queueItem": null,
  "concurrentBuild": false,
  "resumeBlocked": false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Make a POST request to /jenkins/job/**YOURJOBNAME**/build. The response
   contains a location **header** with the **queue id**.
2. Every X seconds, make a GET request to
   /jenkins/job/**YOURJOBNAME**/api/json?tree=builds[building,number,result,queueId].
   The response contains an array of builds for the specified job. Here
   you can filter a build by the queueId, and check its status.
3. The build object can give you a lot of info, but the most important is the number. The number is the id of the build, which you can use later to reference it.
4. (Just an example) - Download all build artifacts:
   /jenkins/job/**YOURJOBNAME**/**THEBUILDNUMBER**/artifact/*zip*/artifacts.zip